# Background image resizing to fit

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

I'm trying to make the background image as professional as possible so I'm thinking it's best to resize it based on the size of the browser or the resolution (not sure what's usually used, but I think browser size makes sense here). The idea is if the viewer screen is small, the background image gets smaller, and as the screen gets bigger, the image expands to fit its maximum size.

I will try a CSS or even Javascript (JQuery) solution as needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you're looking for something like that:

http://css-tricks.com/how-to-resizeable-background-image/

Comment: I just used this 3 days ago and it works awesomely. Just remember to zero your margins and padding of the container the background is applied to, so that it renders the same across all browsers.

Answer (score 5):

You will need to stick to CSS 3 background-size property to achieve this: http://webdesign.about.com/od/styleproperties/p/blspbgsize.htm
Without using CSS 3 you cannot resize the background image in any way on the client.